# Mocking a struct with dependencies in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I saw that [on here](https://medium.com/agrea-technogies/mocking-dependencies-in-go-bb9739fef008), you can have a framework called Mockery generate mocks for interfaces for you. This is close to a big deal, because I am already using testify, which has built-in mock API (which, until now, I have not used yet).

The drawback, however, is that it requires interfaces, whereas the code under test is a struct, with nested dependencies, both business logic and third-party code. I am not in charge of refactoring the code base (thank God), and am looking to mock this

```
package context

//ApplicationContext The context to use if the use of an application is needed.
type ApplicationContext struct {
    DatabaseContext
}

//GetAppId Gets the application id from the session.
func (c *ApplicationContext) GetAppId() int {
    if str := c.GetFromSession("ApplicationId"); str != nil {
        return str.(int)
    }
    return -1
}

//SetAppId Sets the application id into the session.
func (c *ApplicationContext) SetAppId(id int) {
    c.SetToSession("ApplicationId", id)
}
```

which extends `DatabaseContext`, which has `Session.Store` (third-party dependency that is used by those two functions) along with some other dependencies that are none of my concern.

How could I mock this struct?

Comment: You can't. If something accepts a concrete type, that's the only type you can use, not a mock type. You can only mock/stub if it accepts an interface you can implement.

Comment: Poorly-written Java code is also difficult to test. The dynamic classloader that lets you pull all sorts of runtime hijinks in Java comes with a significant runtime complexity and memory cost. There are always tradeoffs.

Comment: Would it then be acceptable to "mock" (by this, I mean 'stub') the `Session.Store` that the code under test relies on under the hood, and then use it?